# =COUNTIFS with multiple criteria but only needing one met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**=COUNTIFS(E6:E53,D60,P6:P53,"<>",S6:S53,"<>")**

I'm currently trying to get the number of initials in the range E6:E53 that is stored in D60.

I also only want to count the initials if the ranges P6:P53 & S6:S53 has any value in the cell.

With the formula I have it is currently just counting the initials without paying attention to the other two criteria.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

If you want if `P6:P53` **AND** `S6:S53` are not Blank:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((E6:E53=D60)*(LEN(P6:P53)>0)*(LEN(S6:S53)>0))
```

If you want if `P6:P53` **OR** `S6:S53` are not Blank:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((E6:E53=D60)*((LEN(P6:P53)>0)+(LEN(S6:S53)>0)>0))
```

Comment: Thank you for this, i have tried but it returns 0 when i know the value should be 5, any ideas as to why that may be?

Comment: Without seeing a mock up of the data, no.  You can make sure that the expected values actually match the value in D60 and there are no extra non printable characters like spaces that would make it not the same.

Comment: I have tried the edit still no luck, i have an example spreadsheet if you have a minute to take a look at it

Comment: I do not download things from unknown sources.  If you have it in a shareable google sheet or Excel online where I can copy paste the data then I will look at it.

Comment: Dont blame you, google sheets link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WDgF5D2GJ8tuc9xtlsYGeF0fiTS9urO8Umqd5ILQlq4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Not sharing.  It is locked.

Comment: My mistake https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WDgF5D2GJ8tuc9xtlsYGeF0fiTS9urO8Umqd5ILQlq4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It works for me.  I put `RB` in `G2` and this in `F2`: `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A48=G2)*((LEN(C1:C48)>0)+(LEN(D1:D48)>0)>0))` and it returned `7`

Comment: Smashing work, thank you very much. not sure what happened yesterday but looks good today.